# Accessing metadata results in a nested pipeline for Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, foreach, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline built that reads metadata from a blob container subfolder raw/subfolder.  I then execute a foreach loop with another get metadata task to get data for each subfolder, it returns the following type of data.  /raw/subfolder1/folder1, /raw/subfolder2/folder1, /raw/subfolder2/folder1 and so on.  I need another foreach loop to access the files inside of each folder.  The problem is that you cannot run a foreach loop inside of another foreach loop so I cannot iterate further on the files.

I have an execute datapipline that calls the above pipeline and then uses a foreach.  My issue with this is that I'm not finding a way to pass the item().name from the above iteration to my new pipeline.  It doesn't appear you can pass in objects form the previous pipeline?  How would I be able to accomplish this nested foreach metat data gathering so I can iterate further on my files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using parameters? Here is how it would look like:

1. In your parent pipeline, click on the "Execute Pipeline" activity which triggers the inner (your new pipeline) go to *Settings* and specify item name as a parameter "name".
   [image]
2. In your inner pipeline, click anywhere on empty space and add new parameter "name". 
   [image]
3. Now you can refer to that parameter like this: pipeline().parameters.name

Comment: I get an error when I try this -

{
    "errorCode": "BadRequest",
    "message": "The expression 'item().name' cannot be evaluated because property 'name' cannot be selected.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "ExecutePiplineDetermineFileSize",
    "details": ""
}

I added in @{item().name} in the name field and @{item().child} in the child field.

In my child pipeline which gets executed from the parent has the parameters:
name set to String with a blank value
child set to Array with a blank value.

don't know how to post pictures :(

Comment: What you said actually works for the most part, what I had wrong was the direction of nesting pipelines.  Once I figured that out I was able to pass the parameters correctly.  I the parent I created the parameters like you said and then in the child I called those parameters to get down to the next level of the file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Using Parameters works in this scenario as @Andrii mentioned. 
For more on passing parameters between activities refer to this link.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/azure-data-factory-passing-parameters/

Comment: this document shows how to use parameters inside of a pipeline which I understand how to do.  I have something very similar in my existing pipeline.  I get meta data from the root folder for childItems.  I then pass that information into a foreach loop to get the next layer of child items.  I cannot add another foreach loop, its not allowed.  So instead I have to create a new pipeline, first execute the other pipeline, then get item and childitems from the other pipeline so I can get filesize for each subfolder.  The directory looks like this rootfolder/directory/subdirectory/files.